# Jquery Sticky navigation fires up when meets certain condition

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have successfully created a sticky navigation and works perfectly fine. However, I want the sticky navigation to fires up or run when the browser is lower than or equal to 770px.

So far, this is my code

```
$j = jQuery.noConflict();

$j(document).ready(function() {
  var navOffset = $j(".main-nav").offset().top;
  var wi = $j(window).width();
  var sticky;
  $j(".responsive-icon").wrapInner('<div class="value"></div>');
  $j(".main-nav").wrap('<div class="nav-placeholder"></div>');
  $j(".nav-placeholder").height($j(".main-nav").outerHeight());

  function stickyFunction() { /*Sticky navigation function*/
    sticky = $j(window).scroll(function() {
              var scrollPos = $j(window).scrollTop();
              if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
                $j(".main-nav").attr("id", "fixed-menu");
              } else {
                $j(".main-nav").removeAttr("id");
              }
            });
    return sticky;
  }

  if(wi <= 770) { /* Suppose to Fires up immediately if the browser is lower than 770px */
      stickyFunction();
    }
  $j(window).resize(function() { /*Suppose to fires up if the browser resize*/
    if(wi <= 770) {
      stickyFunction();
    }
  });
});
```

How do I call the stickyfunction to run when the browser width meets the condition?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

simply you use sticky as a scroll event and try to use scroll event inside window resize event so your function not fired in resize window ..
use this

```
/*Sticky navigation function*/
   var  stickyFunction= (function() {
              var scrollPos = $j(window).scrollTop();
              if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
                $j(".main-nav").attr("id", "fixed-menu");
              } else {
                $j(".main-nav").removeAttr("id");
              }
            });
```

instead of

```
function stickyFunction() { /*Sticky navigation function*/
    sticky = $j(window).scroll(function() {
              var scrollPos = $j(window).scrollTop();
              if (scrollPos >= navOffset) {
                $j(".main-nav").attr("id", "fixed-menu");
              } else {
                $j(".main-nav").removeAttr("id");
              }
            });
    return sticky;
  }
```

and make an event to window scroll

```
$j(window).on('scroll', stickyFunction);
```

and in resize event

```
$j(window).on('resize',function() { /*Suppose to fires up if the browser resize*/
 wi = $j(window).width();        
 if(wi <= 770) {
      stickyFunction();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for simplification and better logic. I want this effect to run only if the browser is lower than 770px.

Comment: @rodge you should calculate the window.width when resize .. see updated answer

Comment: Thanks! the problem was, the width gets updated when browser was resize.